# Ignore certain files (fonts) when building .scss with webpack

Tags: css, webpack, sass, build, fonts

An example directory structure looks like:

Current:

```
example/
├── src/
│   ├── fonts/
│   │   └── OpenSans/
│   │       ├── OpenSans-Regular.woff
│   │       └── ...
│   ├── js/
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── css/
│   │   ├── base/
│   │   │   ├── _font.scss
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── app.js
├── web/
│   ├── build/
│   │   ├── fonts/
│   │   │   ├── OpenSans-Regular.woff
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── app.css
│   │   ├── app.es5.js
│   │   └── app.js
│   └── index.php
├── webpack.common.js
├── webpack.dev.js
└── webpack.prod.js
```

Goal:

```
example/
├── src/
│   ├── js/
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── css/
│   │   ├── base/
│   │   │   ├── _font.scss
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── app.js
├── web/
│   ├── build/
│   │   ├── app.css
│   │   ├── app.es5.js
│   │   └── app.js
│   ├── fonts/
│   │   └── OpenSans/
│   │       ├── OpenSans-Regular.woff
│   │       └── ...
│   └── index.php
├── webpack.common.js
├── webpack.dev.js
└── webpack.prod.js
```

I now need to refer to these font files how the browser ultimately need it. This could look like:

`_font.scss`

Current:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../../fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.eot');
    src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'),
         url('../../fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../../fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.svg#OpenSans-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Goal:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.eot');
    src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'),
         url('/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.svg#OpenSans-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Obviously, I could put the fonts files, in the source folder and include them in the build (which is how it currently is), but that's unnecessary. Also, referring to the fonts file relative to the scss file or absolute from the project root works, but that simply copies the files to the build/ folder. Which makes the build unnecessarily longer and heavier.

**I simply want to put the url in the scss file and the build process should simply copy the value, no resolving, no changing, nothing, just copy.**

For more context, here are the current webpack files:

`webpack.common.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const del = require('del');
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin = require('webpack-remove-empty-scripts');

/*
 * https://github.com/chrisblossom/clean-self-webpack-plugin
 * Remove project files before webpack is loaded.
 * Be sure it is not async.
 *
 * It is HIGHLY recommended to handle the initial
 * build directory clean outside of this plugin / webpack.
 *
 * Popular existing packages:
 * https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf
 * https://github.com/sindresorhus/del
 *    -- I prefer this one, great glob support and has CLI (del-cli package)
 * https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra
 */
del.sync([path.resolve(__dirname, 'web', 'build', '**/*')]);

exports.common = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js',
        styleguide: './src/styleguide.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web', 'build'),
        publicPath: '/build/',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    // This plugin extracts CSS into separate files.
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {},
                    },
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true }
                    },
                    // A tool for transforming CSS with JavaScript
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: [
                                    require('postcss-import')({
                                        plugins: [
                                        ],
                                        path: ['./node_modules'],
                                    }),
                                    require('tailwindcss'),
                                    require('postcss-preset-env')({
                                        autoprefixer: {},
                                        features: {
                                            'nesting-rules': true,

                                            // https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/1190
                                            // BUG: ... from Css Minimizer. Expected an opening square bracket.
                                            'focus-within-pseudo-class': false,
                                        }
                                    }),
                                ]
                            },
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    // A webpack loader that rewrites relative paths in url()
                    // statements based on the original source file.
                    {
                        loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true }
                    },
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true }
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /fonts\/(.*)\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'fonts/[name][ext][query]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /img\/(.*)\.(jp(e)?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'img/[name][ext][query]'
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        /**
         * Remove .js files of sass entrypoint.
         */
        new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin(),
    ]
};
exports.jsModern = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                ['@babel/preset-env', {
                                    modules: false,
                                    useBuiltIns: 'entry',
                                    corejs: '3.12',
                                    targets: {
                                        browsers: [
                                            'Chrome >= 60',
                                            'Safari >= 10.1',
                                            'iOS >= 10.3',
                                            'Firefox >= 54',
                                            'Edge >= 15',
                                        ],
                                    },
                                }]
                            ],
                            cacheDirectory: true,
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    target: ['web', 'es6'],
    plugins: [
        /**
         * A Webpack plugin for generating an asset manifest.
         */
        new WebpackManifestPlugin(),
    ],
};
exports.jsLegacy = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                ['@babel/preset-env', {
                                    modules: false,
                                    useBuiltIns: 'entry',
                                    corejs: '3.12',
                                    targets: {
                                        browsers: [
                                            '> 1%',
                                            'last 2 versions',
                                            'Firefox ESR',
                                        ],
                                    },
                                }]
                            ],
                            cacheDirectory: true,
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    target: ['web', 'es5'],
    plugins: [
        /**
         * A Webpack plugin for generating an asset manifest.
         */
        new WebpackManifestPlugin({
            fileName: 'manifest-legacy.json',
        }),
    ],
};
```

`webpack.dev.js`

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const { common, jsLegacy, jsModern } = require('./webpack.common.js');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const WebpackBar = require('webpackbar');

const dev = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    plugins: [
        /**
         * This plugin extracts CSS into separate files. It creates a CSS file per
         * JS file which contains CSS. It supports On-Demand-Loading of CSS and
         * SourceMaps.
         */
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css'
        }),

        new WebpackBar({}),
    ]
});

module.exports = [
    merge(dev, jsModern, {
        name: 'modern',
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
        },
    }),
    merge(dev, jsLegacy, {
        name: 'legacy',
        output: {
            filename: '[name].es5.js',
        },
    })
];
module.exports.parallelism = 1;
```

**Anybody knows how to achieve this? Or is it impossible?**

Comment: did you find a fix for this yet?

Comment: @AmitPandey no, ever since upgrading webpack back then, i simply include them in the build